# Arguing of Buddhists?

Tags: theravada, lay-buddhism, buddha, academic-buddhism

Q:

> Do Buddhists argue over topics? Wouldn't that be unwholesome and view
>   clinging?

Comment: Suggestion: 'Debate' may be a better word to phrase your question to maintain neutrality. ('Argue' may not be the best word to use if I am correct about the context of your question)

Comment: Ddebating is an effective method for learning. The word 'arguing' suggests something more egotistical than debating, and as you say it can spill over into clinging and dogmatism.

Comment: @Krizalid_13190 Call it "arguing" or "debating" as you wish -- if you think the difference is important you could explain that in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Arguing depends upon person to person. Buddha always forbid arguing. Even at time of buddha , few of his disciples used to argue & he ,by many Upmas(lessons), used to forbid everyone to argue.

By wearing a tag of buddhism or any other tradition , doesn't mean person has become an enlightened one. If somebody is not ready to accept , it's good -let this go otherwise ,if accepts ,it's good ,still ,whatever the case is ,one must be ready to learn(if same is unenlightened) ,mustn't stick to blind-faith.

Moreover , dhamma-discussion can be done peacefully , buddha never restricted dhamma_related_discussion. You are your own master , you cannot force anyone to accept your views ,if you are forcing or arguing that means you are clinging & this is unwholesome.

**Above is for full_time meditators.**

**For house holders::**

Sometimes ,it becomes necessary to argue ,not to fulfill your desire but saving someone's life ,taking important decisions for benefit of large amount of people,etc. In such cases , arguing becomes necessary ,still this must be done while maintaining basic 5 Percepts at body & mental level.